# Power Automate Desktop Password variable error

Tags: power-automate-desktop

I am creating a flow that requires to log into an application.  The password contains !@#$%^& in the password (not full pw).  When I try to input this when setting a variable I am getting a syntax error.  What is the code to force this thru?  I apologize, but I cant figure it out.  I tried "" but that did not resolve the issue.

Tried '' and "" and still get a syntax error.

Comment: Might be on your % character, you should get away with adding %% where one is needed..